# How to use environment variable in json file in development mode in React js with Vite?

Tags: reactjs, json, plugins, environment-variables, vite

I have created an application with React js with Vite implementation in it.
So now I have to use the environment variable in the json file while running the application in development mode.

Attaching some code for reference.

**.env.development**

```
VITE_NODE_ENV=development
VITE_REACT_APP_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000"
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import { TransformOption, viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy';

const copyPlugin = (env: any) => {
  const reactBaseURLtransform: TransformOption = (contents, path) => {
    return contents.replace(/<REACT_APP_BASE_URL>/g, env.VITE_REACT_APP_BASE_URL);
  };

  return viteStaticCopy({
    flatten: true,
    targets: [
      {
        src: 'public/*.json',
        dest: '',
        transform: reactBaseURLtransform,
      }
    ],
  });
};

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
  const plugins: any[] = [react(), viteTsconfigPaths()];
  plugins.push(copyPlugin(env));

  return {
    plugins: [...plugins],
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          manualChunks(id) {
            if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
              return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
            }
          },
        },
      },
      chunkSizeWarningLimit: 5000,
    },
    server: {
      open: false,
      port: 3000,
    },
  };
});
```

Currently with this configuration of Vite, when we build the application using yarn build(which internally runs "vite build"), Vite replaces all the <REACT_APP_BASE_URL> with the URL defined in the .env file.

In the same way, when we start the application using yarn start(which internally runs "vite"), it should replace all the <REACT_APP_BASE_URL> with the URL defined in the .env file but currently it's not doing it.

So what can be the approach to replace all the <REACT_APP_BASE_URL>(defined in json file) with the URL defined in the .env file when we start our application in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a custom Vite plugin
- Use the `transform` hook for JSON files
- Replace `<REACT_APP_BASE_URL>` during development

```js
// Custom plugin in vite.config.js
const replaceBaseUrlPlugin = (env) => {
  return {
    name: 'replace-base-url',
    transform(code, id) {
      if (id.endsWith('.json') && env.VITE_NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        return code.replace(/<REACT_APP_BASE_URL>/g, env.VITE_REACT_APP_BASE_URL);
      }
    },
  };
};

// Add the plugin to your configuration
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
  const plugins: any[] = [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), replaceBaseUrlPlugin(env)];

  // ...
});
```

This should work for replacing `<REACT_APP_BASE_URL>` in JSON files during development.

Comment: I got your solution but I'm not getting how to declare the URL in the json file. If I'm writing like this --> "<REACT_APP_BASE_URL>" it is not replacing the URL.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the variables in the .env file. Originally my .env file was in the src folder and when I put the .env file into the root of the project I was able to get it.